# Writing a test for a custom FormHelper gem patch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, rubygems

I [forked the country_code_select gem](https://github.com/onemanarmy/country_code_select) and made a [fix](https://github.com/onemanarmy/country_code_select/commit/1184d7e9d2a6fddb18b9dc163377e7ddd4198642) because it wasn't generating the ID attribute properly for nested fields_for models.

I've never written tests before or patched a gem - but I'm trying.  This is entirely new to me.

Can you help me write the test case for my [fix](https://github.com/onemanarmy/country_code_select/commit/1184d7e9d2a6fddb18b9dc163377e7ddd4198642) so that I can submit my first ever gem patch?

I tried using `form_for` and `fields_for` in `spec/form_helpers_spec` but that just took me down a rabbit hole.

---

Additional info that may help:

**Client.rb**

```
has_one :billing_address
accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address
```

**View:**

```
<%= form_for @client do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :billing_address, @client.billing_address  do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.country_code_select(:country_code) %>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have tests already! In you forked repo, there's [this line](https://github.com/onemanarmy/country_code_select/blob/master/spec/form_helpers_spec.rb#L16). Just copy this test case to create a new comparison if your modification works as it should and **without braking the old specs**.

If you need more examples or schooling, look at [how rails tests view helpers](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/test/template/form_helper_test.rb#L126). Be aware though, that they write these helpers for themselves and they use other testing framework than your fork.

Not so accurate example:

```
it "should output a valid select field for fields_for nested attributes" do
  # in the next line, pass such parameters to this function
  # so that your particular modification to the code is triggered
  output = country_code_select(:client, :billing_address, :country_code)

  # and here check if your code works as it should
  # I think you're modifying how id is assigned with nesting fields,
  # so test something like this:
  output.should match(/select id="client_billing_address_country_code"/)
end
```

I also recommend reading about tests, if you want to get deeper with this. There's a **lot** to it, but I found that [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) helped me to produce better, more reliable code and I think it's worth the *extra* effort.

Since it's your first contribution, Welcome to the Open Source community and good luck with your contributions :)